# Requiring a package is causing an error

Tags: javascript, webpack

Each time I am bundling scripts, I have following error:

```
ERROR in ./resources/assets/scripts/main.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'datatables.net-colreorder-bs4' in '/home/vagrant/sites/laravel/resources/assets/scripts'
 @ ./resources/assets/scripts/main.js 12:23-63
```

My webpack config js:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry:  './resources/assets/scripts/main.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './public/js'),
        filename: 'mainBundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['env']
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    stats: {
        colors: true
    },
    node: {
        fs: 'empty'
    },
    devtool: 'source-map'
};
```

And my main js file looks like this (no other modules are causing any problems).

```
var jszip = require('jszip');
var pdfmake = require('pdfmake');
var netBs4 = require('datatables.net-bs4')();
var netButtonsBs4 = require('datatables.net-buttons-bs4')();
var buttonsHtml5 = require('datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.html5.js')();
var buttonsPrint = require('datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.print.js')();
var netColreorderBs4 = require('datatables.net-colreorder-bs4')();
var netReponsiveBs4 = require('datatables.net-responsive-bs4')();
```

I checked the path and it is ok, I also changed the path to absolute but it did not have any effect.

package json:

```
"dependencies": {
        "add": "^2.0.6",
        "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
        "chart.js": "^2.7.1",
        "datatables.net-bs4": "^1.10.16",
        "datatables.net-buttons-bs4": "^1.5.1",
        "datatables.net-colreorder-bs4": "^1.4.1",
        "datatables.net-responsive-bs4": "^2.2.1",
        "gulp-changed": "^3.2.0",
        "gulp-debug": "^3.2.0",
        "jquery": "^3.2.1",
        "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
        "jszip": "^3.1.5",
```

This question is still not resolved, for some reason 'datatables.net-colreorder-bs4' will not be found when using npm... I decided to load it as a ready to use bundle instead of webpacking it...

Comment: Did you install with npm? What is the package.json? It should just work if you did `npm install -S jszip pdfmake ...` Or if you have them in the package.json you can just npm install.

Comment: I did install with npm

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that may be missing is `resolve` but I'm not sure if webpack looks in node_modules by default:

```
module.exports = {
  entry:  './resources/assets/scripts/main.js',
  output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, './public/js'),
      filename: 'mainBundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [
      resolve("./node_modules/")
    ]
  },
```

Would be strange if that is the case because other modules are found.

Answer (score 0):

To use pdfmake in client side mode, you need to use build version directly:

```
window.pdfMake = require('pdfmake/build/pdfmake.js');
var vfs = require('pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts.js');
window.pdfMake.vfs = vfs.pdfMake.vfs;
```